# how to get users' gender by ids using FQL query?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-fql

How to get gender of more user by user's id using fql query?

I have ex 3 user id: userId1, userId2, userId3.

I would like to select gender in 1 query using  something like this:

SELECT uid, gender FROM friend WHERE uid IN ( userId1, userId2, userId3)

I know is a wrong query.

Comment: what you gonna do? your query is right BTW

Comment: I get this error :   "message": "(#602) uid is not a member of the friend table.", and without uid : "message": "(#602) gender is not a member of the friend table.". I need to get gender of userid1/2/3

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the correct table! You must use the `user` table like this:

```
SELECT uid, sex FROM user WHERE uid IN (userId1, userId2, userId3)
```

Be aware that FQL access will be deprecated on April 30th, 2015. It's better to use the pure Graph API like this:

```
GET /?ids=userId1,userId2,userId3&fields=id,gender
```

For Graph API v2.0, the application-specific user_id has to be used

Comment: thanks! but I get this error:   "error": {
    "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: {155xxx629},{1000xxxx972637},{15xxx910}", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 803

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/?ids={userId1},{userId2},{userId3}&fields=id,gender

Comment: You need to remove the curly brackets!!

Comment: It's right. i get this error: "message": "The global ID 15xxxx29 is not allowed. Please use the application specific ID instead.",

Comment: Yes, with v2.0 of the Graph API you have to use app-specific user_ids! You can switch to v1.0, but this will only work until April 30th, 2015 then.

Comment: how can i get app-specific user_ids?

Comment: Use an app which uses v2.0 of the Graph API? Call `/me` and you'll see your user_id specific to this app

Comment: So can I get application-specific user_id only whether
the user are using my application?

Comment: Ok I'm using application-specific user_id but gender  is not aviable (as profice pic)